# Como apagar os dados da JTable e inserilos novamente?

Tags: java, swing, awt

Atravez de um botao que tem coo função atualizar a table quero que os dados sejam retirados e voltem em seguida, meu codigo ate entao esta assim:

```
public class atualizando implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        if (arg0.getSource() == btnAtualizar) {

            DefaultTableModel tblRemove = (DefaultTableModel) tabela.getModel();
            DefaultTableModel tblRemove2 = (DefaultTableModel) tabela2.getModel();

                while (tabela.getModel().getRowCount() > 0) {  
                       ((DefaultTableModel) tabela.getModel()).removeRow(0);  
                   }
            while(tabela2.getModel().getRowCount() > 0) {
                ((DefaultTableModel) tabela2.getModel()).removeRow(0);  
            }


            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                EnderecoDB = "jdbc:mysql://22.222.222:3306/system";
                Conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(EnderecoDB, "estoque", "123456");
                Comando = Conexao.createStatement();

                ResultSet rsRegistro3;
                rsRegistro3 = Comando.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Produtos ORDER BY Referencia");

                String Campo3[] = new String [4];
                int intNumRegistro3 = 0,intRegistro3 = 0;
                rsRegistro3.beforeFirst();
                rsRegistro3.next();
                intRegistro3 = rsRegistro3.getInt("Num_venda");
                Campo3[0] = Integer.toString(intRegistro3);
                Campo3[1] = rsRegistro3.getString("Produto");
                Campo3[2] = rsRegistro3.getString("Preco");
                Campo3[3] = rsRegistro3.getString("quantidade");
                ModeloAgenda2.insertRow(0, Campo);

                intNumRegistro3 = 1;
                while(rsRegistro.next()) {
                    intRegistro3 = rsRegistro3.getInt("Num_venda");
                    Campo3[0] = Integer.toString(intRegistro3);
                    Campo3[1] = rsRegistro3.getString("Produto");
                    Campo3[2] = rsRegistro3.getString("Preco");
                    Campo3[3] = rsRegistro3.getString("quantidade");
                    ModeloAgenda2.insertRow(intNumRegistro3, Campo3);
                }

            }catch(Exception e ) {
                System.out.println("deu um erro: "+e);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Testou assim: `removeRow.setNumRows(0)` ?

Comment: @adventistaam esse comando ai está obsoleto do java desde a versao 3.

Answer (score 0):

Para apagar todos os dados, você utiliza o método `setRowCount(0);` que faz parte o TableModel:

```
if (arg0.getSource() == btnAtualizar) {

    DefaultTableModel tblRemove = (DefaultTableModel) tabela.getModel();
    DefaultTableModel tblRemove2 = (DefaultTableModel) tabela2.getModel();

        while (tabela.getModel().getRowCount() > 0) {  
               ((DefaultTableModel) tabela.getModel()).setRowCount(0);  
           }
    while(tabela2.getModel().getRowCount() > 0) {
        ((DefaultTableModel) tabela2.getModel()).setRowCount(0); 
    }
```

Referencia:

[how to clear JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4578501/5524514)

Answer (score -2):

Eu trabalho com JavaFX tableview, que é mais chatinha.
Veja se tem o comando:

```html
tabela.removeAll();
```

Em seguida você preenche ela com os novos dados.

Uma dica, não fique criando conexão do o DB toda hora, com o tempo você terá centenas de conexões de uma mesma pessoa.
Crie a conexão apenas 1 vez.
Depois quando vc quiser usar ela, basta chamar o prepareStatement(linhasql); depois o executeQuery();

Valeu.

Comment: Não tem esse método no java swing.